# Can a JWT generated in a programming language be consumed by another programming language?

Tags: jwt

I am thinking about Generating a JWT token using, I don't know, NodeJS and consume it in a C# application. According to my knowledge, if I have the secret key I can use the Token normally. There's nothing in a token that attachs it to the system that generated it. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. JWT is independent from the language and systems on which they're created or consumed.

JWT is a proposed [IETF](https://ietf.org/about/who/) (Internet Engineering Task Force) standard, documented in [RFC7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519).

On [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/#libraries-io) you can find a list of libraries for many languages.

When creator (authentication server) and consumer (resource server) are different systems, you would normally work with asymmetric algorithms (e.g. RS256) and use the private key to sign and the public key to verify the token.